# Conditional expected value dice game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

Dice game, where you sum up the amount based on the number rolled. Z is the total sum. Game ends if you roll a 1, and you don't add the value of 1 to your existing sum. What's the expected value of the total sum (Z)?

Comment: How are points awarded precisely and to what degree do you have a choice? What are your goals?

Comment: Just roll until you hit a 1, and you're adding up the values of the rolls after each time.

Answer (score 1):

The average result of a die roll that is not a $1$ will be $4$.  There will be an expected number of $6$ die rolls until you roll a $1$, making it an expected number of $5$ die rolls that contribute to your score.

You get then $4\times 5 = 20$ points on average.